# Permission Issues for Office365 Workflow.aspx Page

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

Im using Sharepoint Office 365 and I have custom workflows. I need the user to see only his workflow approval task on workflow.aspx page. But the workflow shows the name of all assigned to people as it assigns to the whole group (parallel and wait for 1st response only). How can I restrict the user to see only his name? Where are the settings? I can't access the workflow.aspx page for Sharepoint O365, this was restricted in on-premises 2013 by someone else and the client wants the same functionality on cloud as well. Thery are not willing to response through the Task List but they want to got through the workflow page.

[image]

User A,B,C sees the workflow tasks for each other. I want the user A to see only his name if he is logged in and similarly B and C.Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a SharePoint 2010 workflow on the Tasks list and design it like the below:
[image]

And for the workflow start options, set it:
[image]

Comment: Thank you @Kally_MSFT. But it didnt work. It still shows the users the tasks for each other. Do I need to do anything before I create this workflow like register the app or something ?

Comment: Doesn't replace Full Control gives the users full control to item? How can other users are restricted to even viewing this item which are not Assigned To them ? here workflow is assigned to a group

Comment: After running the workflow, Replace Full control Permissions action will give the Assigned To user Full control on the current item, and other users will not see the current item. A thing you need to notice is that you need to use a user who has Full control on the site to create the workflow with SharePoint Designer.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

@Kally_MSFT I tried the following and used the Workflow Start Options . But it didnot seem to work. Can you please suggest something else or am I missing something here?